# Change UITextField text right before editing when using custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield

I'm have a weird issue here. I have a UITableView using custom UITableViewCells. Everything is working as expected except this on particular issue.

*Here's the scenario:*

I need to remove the "$" symbol in a UITextField right before editing begins. This is done via the `textFieldShouldBeginEditing:` method.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    LifeEarningsLineItemTableViewCell *cell = (LifeEarningsLineItemTableViewCell *)[self tableViewCellContainingObject:textField inTableView:self.lifeEarningsTableView];
    if (textField == cell.itemAmount) {
        /*Remove currency symbol for editing.*/
        NSString *currencySymbol = [self.currencyFormatter currencySymbol];
        NSMutableString *mutableText = [NSMutableString stringWithString:textField.text];
        [mutableText replaceOccurrencesOfString:currencySymbol withString:@"" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [mutableText length])];
        textField.text = mutableText;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

*Here's the problem:*

- Between **different** rows, moving from textField1 to textField2 (in a different row), the "$" **is** removed, this is **GOOD**.
- Within the **same** row, moving from textField1 to textField2, the "$" **is not** removed, this is **BAD**.

Why is the "$" not being removed within the same row, but does in different rows?

Here's is a visual representation of the issue:  [image: Issue]

[EDIT...ADDITION]
I get these logs with these flows:

[image: Flow1]
SHOULD BEGIN.....Row:0, Tag:0
SHOULD BEGIN.....Row:0, Tag:1
DID END.....Row:0, Tag:0
DID END.....Row:0, Tag:1

[image: Flow2]
SHOULD BEGIN.....Row:0, Tag:0
SHOULD BEGIN.....Row:1, Tag:1
DID END.....Row:0, Tag:0
DID END.....Row:1, Tag:1

Also, here is the `tableViewCellContainingObject:inTableView:tableView` method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableViewCellContainingObject:(UIView *)view inTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    CGPoint objectRectInTableViewCoordinates = [tableView convertPoint:view.bounds.origin fromView:view];
    NSIndexPath *cellIndexPath = [tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:objectRectInTableViewCoordinates];
    return [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:cellIndexPath];
}
```

And the  `textFieldDidEndEditing` method:

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    LifeEarningsLineItemTableViewCell *cell = (LifeEarningsLineItemTableViewCell *)[self tableViewCellContainingObject:textField inTableView:self.lifeEarningsTableView];
    LifeEarningsLineItem *lifeEarningsLineItem = [self.lifeEarningsFetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:[self.lifeEarningsTableView indexPathForCell:cell]];

    if (textField == cell.itemAmount) {
        NSNumber *absInteger = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:abs([textField.text integerValue])];
        textField.text = [self.currencyFormatter stringFromNumber:absInteger];
        lifeEarningsLineItem.amount = absInteger;
        [self sumAmountsAndDisplay];
    } else if (textField == cell.itemName) {
        lifeEarningsLineItem.name = textField.text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, about the only thing that it could be is that for some reason (you don't show the code for it) `tableViewCellContainingObject: inTableView:` is not returning the correct cell when this happens.

Comment: I checked that through log statements via `indexPathForCell:`. Not only did it log the correct rows, it also logged the correct values for those UITextFields via `theTextField.text`. From the above code, when I log `textField.text`, it actually logs the correct text (no "$")! Yet it it displays visually the "$" symbol. FYI, this is through the simulator (iOS 5.1).

Comment: If you log `textField.text` and it shows the correct value, does it by any chance remove the $ from a different row?

Comment: No, the other rows (3 rows for test purposes) are untouched. I feel it has something to do with the UITableViewCell not refreshing its display when switching between text fields within the same row (cell).

Comment: Well, the UITextField refreshes it's view when you change the text though....

Comment: Yes. The value does refresh while editing.

Comment: So I guess that you are adding the $ back in with `textFieldShouldEndEditing`?  Really, the only thing that makes sense is that it is acting on the wrong row, and when it ends editing on the wrong row, it adds the $ back in.  break on both of those functions and see how many times they get called when you try it.  I'm guessing when you go straight across, you get an end and then a begin but when you switch you get an end, a begin, and an end.

Comment: I made some additions above. Yes, I am adding the "$" back in the `textFieldDidEndEditing`. I see what you are saying, but in my implementation, I'm always referring to the local `textField` parameter in the delegate methods, so I'm not sure if that would throw it off.

Comment: This really all looks good.  If you put a NSLog after `/*Remove currency symbol for editing.*/` comment, does it get called in both situations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your solution (decoupling the FRC during editing) may be a little drastic and could have unforeseen effects. Here are a couple of alternative suggestions. I am assuming the problem is caused by the table reloading the row you are editing once you have finished editing the first field in the cell.

- Don't store the currency symbol in your model, add it to the displayed text in cellForRowAtIndexPath, *if* the text field is not editing. When your textfield begins editing, set its text to the value directly from the model. You don't have to do anything in end editing since the reload will add the currency symbol back on for you.
- If you dont want to change the model, you can do something similar anyway - in cellForRowAtIndexPath remove the currency symbol if the cell is editing.
- Store the index path of the currently editing row and conditionally ignore changes to this row in the FRC delegate method.

Comment: Specifically the first bullet point. I already store an NSNumber into my model (i.e. no $ is saved). But the suggestion "_add it to the displayed text in cellForRowAtIndexPath, **if** the text field is not editing_", the **if** was a nice simple approach. I totally overlooked this as a good place to check if text field is editing. So within my `configureCell` (called in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`), the new edited line: `if (lifeEarningsLineItemCell.itemAmount.editing == NO) lifeEarningsLineItemCell.itemAmount.text = [self.currencyFormatter stringFromNumber:lifeEarningsLineItem.amount];`.  Thanks.

Comment: Happy to help. I know how it feels to stare at a problem all day and miss an obvious solution!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I figured out the problem...it was the gosh darn `NSFetchedResultsController` delegate methods, specifically the `NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate` change type. This is not the first time where `NSFetchedResultsController` walked all over my table. I should have remembered that `NSFetchedResultsController` doesn't play well with user-driven edits.

So here is how I have resolved the issue (but I'm still in fear that the whole thing could all come crashing down):

Because of the order of events...

```
SHOULD BEGIN.....Row:0, Tag:0  
SHOULD BEGIN.....Row:0, Tag:1  
DID END.....Row:0, Tag:0  
DID END.....Row:0, Tag:1
```

...I couldn't just use a `BOOL` property to say a text field was in editing mode (the order of events would have to be BEGIN->END->BEGIN->END).

So I created the property:
`@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableSet *stackOfEditingTextFields;`

Then at the start of `textFieldShouldBeginEditing:` method, I added:

```
/*Add text field to stack of editing text fields and disable the fetched results controller delegate.*/
[self.stackOfEditingTextFields addObject:textField];
self.lifeEarningsFetchedResultsController.delegate = nil;
```

Then at the end of `textFieldDidEndEditing:` method, I added:

```
/*Remove text field from stack of editing text fields. If stack count is 0, reengage the fetched results controller delegate.*/
[self.stackOfEditingTextFields removeObject:textField];
if ([self.stackOfEditingTextFields count] == 0) self.lifeEarningsFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
```

If there's a better suggestion or any unforeseen bi-product bugs that I'm not seeing, I'm all ears.

Thanks for the help [lnafziger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/937822/lnafziger), in helping me work through it, and suggesting different angles (I +1'd your comments).

Comment: Glad you worked it out, but I share your concerns about the solution. What happens if you leave the app or switch to another tab during editing, does the keyboard dismiss AND the FRC delegate get re-attached?